# Display the frequency of occurrence of words, and the words themselves

Tags: java, collections, compareto

**Here are entered word and called container, which is a collection of storage words.**

```
public class Part1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordContainer wc = new WordContainer();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        while (in.hasNextLine() && !"stop".equals(line = in.nextLine())) {
            wc.put(new Word(line));
        }

        in.close();
        print();

    }


    public static void print() {
        for (Word w : WordContainer.al) {
            System.out.println(w + ": " + w.getfrequency());
        }
    }
}
```

**A container that stores word. If the word is in the sheet, we increase the frequency, if not - add a new word**

```
public class WordContainer {

public static ArrayList<Word> al = new ArrayList<Word>();

public Word put(Word s) {
    for (Word w : al) {
        if (w.s.compareTo(s.getWord()) == 0) {
            s.setfrequency();
        } else {
            al.add(new Word());
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

}

**This class of words where the word is stored and the frequency of their occurrence**

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
String s = "";
private int frequency = 0;

Word(String s) {
    this.s = s;
    frequency = 1;
}

Word() {
    setfrequency();
}

public void setfrequency() {
    ++frequency;
}

public int getfrequency() {
    return frequency;
}


public String getWord() {
    return s;
}

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word o) {
        return s.compareTo(o.getWord());
    }
}
```

I can not understand why it does not work.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

In case don't find a word, you add a new `Word` with a empty string instead of just the `Word` passed as parameter (or a copy with the same content). Furthermore you add a new `Word` for **every** `Word` where the content doesn't match...

Also the enhanced for loop tries to continue iterating through the list after it's modified, which leads to a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Furthermore you'll probably want to return the `Word` from the list, not the one passed as parameter

Change the code as follows:

```
public Word put(Word s) {
    for (Word w : al) {
        if (w.s.compareTo(s.getWord()) == 0) {
            w.setfrequency();

            // found it, now stop searching
            return w;
        }
    }
    // didn't find it; insert
    al.add(s);
    return s;
}
```

#### Notes on the design

There are several things in your code that I'd consider bad design:

- You're using a `static` list in `WordContainer`, however the `put` method is a instance method. This means the data will be shared accross all instances of `WordContainer`, but you need to create a instance to call `put`. The list should be a non-`static` field too.
- The "internal data" of the `WordContainer` class is `public`. Furthermore `Word` is modifiable (you can call `setfrequency` on it), which lets you easily break encapsulation. The simplest way of fixing this would be making the `Word` class a inner class of `WordContainer`, changing the `setfrequency` method to `private` and passing a `String` to the `put` method.

```
public class WordContainer {

    public static class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
        private final String s;
        private int frequency;

        private Word(String s) {
            this.s = s;
            frequency = 1;
        }

        /*Word() {
            this("");
        }*/

        private void setfrequency() {
            ++frequency;
        }

        public int getfrequency() {
            return frequency;
        }


        public String getWord() {
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Word o) {
            return s.compareTo(o.getWord());
        }
    }

    private final List<Word> al = new ArrayList<Word>();
    private final List<Word> unmodifiableWords = Collections.unmodifiableList(al);

    public Word put(String s) {
        for (Word w : al) {
            if (w.s.equals(s)) {
                w.setfrequency();
                return w;
            }
        }
        Word word = new Word(s);
        al.add(word);
        return word;
    }

    public List<Word> getWords() {
         // do not allow for external modification of the list
         return unmodifiableWords;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your `put` method in your class `WordContainer`. You are adding a new `Word` object to your list rather than using the one passed in your method.

```
if (w.s.compareTo(s.getWord()) == 0) {
   s.setfrequency();
} else {
   al.add(new Word());  // This is the likely reason, remove this line
                        // you should not be adding a new object

   al.add(s);           // Try this, you should be adding the object s
}
```

UPDATE :

There are 2 changes need to your existing implementation, I didn't realized that before.

First of all, you need to look if you list in `WordContainer` has already got that word or not. If not then you need to add it.

And second, for that to work, you need to override equals method in your Word method as the `contains` method would try to compare objects using `equals`

```
public Word put(Word s) {
        if (al.contains(s)) {
            for (Word w : al) {
                if (w.s.compareTo(s.getWord()) == 0) {
                    s.setfrequency();
                }// else {           //Remove this else, as you add element outside
                 // al.add(s);
                 //}
            }
        } else
            al.add(s);
        return s;
    }
```

And override `equals` method in your `Word` class. Typical override method generated by Eclipse would look like :

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Word other = (Word) obj;
        if (frequency != other.frequency)
            return false;
        if (s == null) {
            if (other.s != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!s.equals(other.s))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

UPDATE 2 :

Answer by Fabian is a nice and elegant way to do it.

Comment: I corrected, but the program still does not display:

 public Word put(Word s) {
  for (Word w : al) {
   if (w.s.compareTo(s.getWord()) == 0) {
       s.setfrequency();
    } else {
        al.add(s); 
    }
  }
  return s;

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shoot at a problem. I think issue is in WordContainer put method.

```
public class WordContainer {

public static ArrayList<Word> al = new ArrayList<Word>();
public Word put(Word s) {
    for (Word w : al) {
        if (w.s.compareTo(s.getWord()) == 0) {
            //s.setfrequency();
            w.setfrequency(); // <-- set frequency of existing word in al
            return w; // <-- return word object that is in al
        }
        // no need to add new word to list after every failed comparison 
        // unless that's what you want to do.
    }
    al.add(s);
    return s;
}
```